# How to implement custom repository based on JpaRepository in spring?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data, querydsl, one-to-one

Context:
I used queryDSL in API controller which binds query to the database get. Currently, I have two tables with OneToOne relationship, and we can call them Table A and Table B. If there are 3 rows in A and 2 rows in B, when I get list A with some conditions, and the queryDSL will generate query SQL like **A CROSS JOIN B WHERE A.id=B.a_id**, but it will miss one item in A. Thus, I am going to implement custom repository to support change join type when generating the SQL statement. The following is some parts of my code:
(Table A is named LabelTask and Table B is named AuditTask)

and generated sql segment is

```
    from
    label_task labeltask0_ cross 
join
    audit_task audittask1_ 
where
    labeltask0_.id=audittask1_.label_task
```

**Is there something wrong with my code or is there another good solution for this situation?**

### JoinDescriptor.java

```
public class JoinDescriptor {

    public final EntityPath path;
    public final JoinType type;

    private JoinDescriptor(EntityPath path, JoinType type) {
        this.path = path;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public static JoinDescriptor innerJoin(EntityPath path) {
        return new JoinDescriptor(path, JoinType.INNERJOIN);
    }

    public static JoinDescriptor join(EntityPath path) {
        return new JoinDescriptor(path, JoinType.JOIN);
    }

    public static JoinDescriptor leftJoin(EntityPath path) {
        return new JoinDescriptor(path, JoinType.LEFTJOIN);
    }

    public static JoinDescriptor rightJoin(EntityPath path) {
        return new JoinDescriptor(path, JoinType.RIGHTJOIN);
    }

    public static JoinDescriptor fullJoin(EntityPath path) {
        return new JoinDescriptor(path, JoinType.FULLJOIN);
    }
}
```

### JoinFetchCapableQueryDslJpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java

```
public class JoinFetchCapableQueryDslJpaRepositoryFactoryBean<R extends JpaRepository<T, I>, T, I extends Serializable>
    extends JpaRepositoryFactoryBean<R, T, I> {

    public JoinFetchCapableQueryDslJpaRepositoryFactoryBean(Class<? extends R> repositoryInterface) {
        super(repositoryInterface);
    }

    protected RepositoryFactorySupport createRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {
        return new JoinFetchCapableQueryDslJpaRepositoryFactory(entityManager);
    }

    private static class JoinFetchCapableQueryDslJpaRepositoryFactory<T, I extends Serializable> extends JpaRepositoryFactory {

        private EntityManager entityManager;

        public JoinFetchCapableQueryDslJpaRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {
            super(entityManager);
            this.entityManager = entityManager;
        }

        protected Object getTargetRepository(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {
            return new JoinFetchCapableRepositoryImpl<>(getEntityInformation(metadata.getDomainType()), entityManager);
        }

        protected Class<?> getRepositoryBaseClass(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {
            return JoinFetchCapableRepository.class;
        }
    }
}
```

### JoinFetchCapableRepository.java

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface JoinFetchCapableRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends
        JpaRepository<T, ID>,
        QuerydslPredicateExecutor<T> {

    Page<T> findAll(Predicate predicate,
                Pageable pageable,
                JoinDescriptor... joinDescriptors);
}
```

### JoinFetchCapableRepositoryImpl.java

```
public class JoinFetchCapableRepositoryImpl <T, ID extends Serializable>
    extends QuerydslJpaRepository<T, ID>
    implements JoinFetchCapableRepository<T, ID> {

   private static final EntityPathResolver DEFAULT_ENTITY_PATH_RESOLVER = SimpleEntityPathResolver.INSTANCE;

   private final EntityPath<T> path;
   private final PathBuilder<T> builder;
   private final Querydsl querydsl;

   public JoinFetchCapableRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation<T, ID> entityInformation,
                                         EntityManager entityManager) {
       this(entityInformation, entityManager, DEFAULT_ENTITY_PATH_RESOLVER);
   }

   public JoinFetchCapableRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation<T, ID> entityInformation,
                                         EntityManager entityManager,
                                         EntityPathResolver resolver) {
       super(entityInformation, entityManager, resolver);
       this.path = resolver.createPath(entityInformation.getJavaType());
       this.builder = new PathBuilder<>(path.getType(), path.getMetadata());
       this.querydsl = new Querydsl(entityManager, builder);
   }

   @Override
   public Page<T> findAll(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable, JoinDescriptor... joinDescriptors) {
       JPQLQuery countQuery = createQuery(predicate);
       JPQLQuery query = querydsl.applyPagination(pageable, createFetchQuery(predicate, joinDescriptors));

       Long total = countQuery.fetchCount();
       List<T> content = total > pageable.getOffset()
                                           ? query.fetch()
                                           : Collections.emptyList();

       return new PageImpl<>(content, pageable, total);
   }

   private JPQLQuery createFetchQuery(Predicate predicate, JoinDescriptor... joinDescriptors) {
       JPQLQuery query = querydsl.createQuery(path);
       for(JoinDescriptor joinDescriptor: joinDescriptors)
           join(joinDescriptor, query);
       return (JPQLQuery) query.where(predicate);
   }

   private JPQLQuery join(JoinDescriptor joinDescriptor, JPQLQuery query) {
       switch(joinDescriptor.type) {
           case DEFAULT:
               throw new IllegalArgumentException("cross join not supported");
           case INNERJOIN:
               query.innerJoin(joinDescriptor.path);
               break;
           case JOIN:
               query.join(joinDescriptor.path);
               break;
           case LEFTJOIN:
               query.leftJoin(joinDescriptor.path);
               break;
           case RIGHTJOIN:
               query.rightJoin(joinDescriptor.path);
               break;
           case FULLJOIN:
               query.join(joinDescriptor.path);
               break;
       }
       return query.fetchAll();
   }
}
```

### JpaConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.some.company.service.repository",
        repositoryFactoryBeanClass =JoinFetchCapableQueryDslJpaRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
public class JpaConfig {}
```

### LabelTaskRepository

```
@Repository
public interface LabelTaskRepository extends
    JoinFetchCapableRepository<LabelTask, String>,
    QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QLabelTask> {

    @Override
    default void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, QLabelTask qLabelTask){
        this.bindQueryByTaskType(bindings, qLabelTask);
        this.bindQueryByCreatedDateRange(bindings, qLabelTask);
        // TODO: should remove this when task could be able to assign
        bindings.excluding(qLabelTask.status);
    }
    ...
}
```

**Result:**
when I launch the spring application, It will return the following error message:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'auditTaskController' defined in file [/.../some/company/service/controllers/AuditTaskController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'auditTaskService' defined in file [/.../some/company/service/AuditTaskService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'auditTaskRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No suitable constructor found on interface some.company.utils.JoinFetchCapableRepository to match the given arguments: [class org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation, class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy182]. Make sure you implement a constructor taking these
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:733)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:198)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1266)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:548)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:386)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:127)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
```

Comment: Usually I set the injection annotation (something that extends @Component) into the implementation class not the interface. The component is instanciated with its autowired dependencies or those defined in the constructor if you use injection through your constructor.

Comment: @uncleBounty thank you for sharing, yes, generally it uses annotation and injection to get an instance. But for the custom repository in Jpa, it need use this approach to override the default implements and get instance via factory method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No suitable constructor found on interface
>   some.company.utils.JoinFetchCapableRepository to match the given
>   arguments: [class
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.**JpaMetamodelEntityInformation**,
>   class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy182].

Based on the exception message, JoinFetchCapableRepositoryImpl needs a constructor which receives two parameters: JpaMetamodelEntityInformation, $Proxy182.

I added a constructor like this:

```
       public JoinFetchCapableRepositoryImpl(
                JpaMetamodelEntityInformation<T, ID> entityInformation,
                EntityManager entityManager) {

           this(entityInformation, entityManager, DEFAULT_ENTITY_PATH_RESOLVER);
       }
```

After this, It works for me and is able to change join type for query dsl